# Module not found: Can't resolve 'D:\NextJs\trial-app\node_modules\lucide-react\dist\cjs\icons\check'

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have been building a Next js app with dark mode functionality from shadcn. I followed all steps from shadcn and install all modules but when I run the app, it gives me this error.
I think its because of the lucide-react-icons. I tried fixing but its not.
Any Solutions?

I tried installing lucid react but its not working.

Comment: Your question would be clearer if you add the error message (which is currently *only* in your title) into the body of the question itself as well. Error messages are usually formatted in a code block or `in backticks like this`.

Answer (score 25):

I had same error. The workaround is to downgrade lucide-react to 0.263.1

```
npm install lucide-react@0.263.1
```

Comment: https://github.com/lucide-icons/lucide/issues/1482

Answer (score 4):

This is an issue from the new Nextjs upgrade, but there are easy workaround, you can just import from your node modules like:

`import { Sun, Moon } from '../../node_modules/lucide-react';`
Or downgrade your Lucide react to  `"lucide-react": "0.263.1",` just
`npm install lucide-react@0.263.1`

Answer (score 2):

This is a mapping issue has now been resolved by Vercel and will be part of next nextjs release:
You can see the fix here: https://github.com/lucide-icons/lucide/issues/1482#issuecomment-1672744695

> Please wait for the next release … or downgrade to lucide-react version 0.263.1 using
> `pnpm add lucide-react@0.263.1`